# Remove the element from the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var arr = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cat", "bird", "dog", "dog","cat"];
arr.remove("cat", "dog");
console.log(arr);
```

I want to delete the string "cat" and "dog" but I want to print them only one time in the result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So you want to delete duplicates, or just delete the cat and dog values once and leave other duplicates after that?

Comment: I want to delete duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the filter function.

```js
var arr = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cat", "bird", "dog", "dog","cat"];
arr = arr.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return arr.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `remove()` method on the default `Array object`.
You have to get the index of the elements, you want to remove and then use the [splice() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
const arr = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cat", "bird", "dog", "dog","cat"];
const toRemove = ["cat", "dog"];

console.log('before', arr);

toRemove.forEach(item => {
  const itemPosition = arr.indexOf(item);
  arr.splice(itemPosition, 1);
});

console.log('after', arr);
```

If you want to make the array unique, you can do the following:

```js
const arr = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cat", "bird", "dog", "dog","cat"];

uniqueArray = arr.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: the dog is repeated twice in result?

Comment: Ah, didn't see there are multiple elements. You should make the array unique first, if that's an option for you.

Comment: That's what this place is for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * Takes an array of primitive values and returns a list with unique values
 *
 * @param {(string[] | number[] | boolean[])} arr
 * @param {boolean} [preserve=false]
 * @returns
 */
function uniqueArray(arr, preserve) {
  if (preserve === void 0) {
    preserve = true;
  }
  //Handle preservation of original array
  var newArr;
  if (preserve === true) {
    newArr = arr.slice(0);
  } else {
    newArr = arr;
  }
  //Loop through array, from lowest to highest index
  for (var a = 0; a < newArr.length; a++) {
    //Loop through remainder of array based on index a
    for (var b = a + 1; b < newArr.length; b++) {
      //If values are the same
      if (newArr[a] === newArr[b]) {
        //Remove this index in the array
        newArr.splice(b, 1);
        //Offset b index to handle the rearranged array
        b--;
      }
    }
  }
  //Return unique array
  return newArr;
}
//TEST
var arr = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cat", "bird", "dog", "dog", "cat"];
console.log(uniqueArray(arr));
```